# text input for each line in foreach table

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

i have
{#each meData as data}
for showing an array and I need to get a text input for each line, how it can define the bind:value so i can save and relate the different values.
using sveltekit
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bind:value` in combination with an array or object.

For the array approach you would simply use the index of the item, note that this can get messed up if your original array changes (sorted, filtered, updated) as the indices will be out of sync.

```html
<script>
let values = []
</script>

{#each array as item, i}
  <input type="text" bind:value={values[i]}>
{/each}
```

Another approach is to use a unique identifier and bind to the property of an object.  Here you have to be aware that even if the item goes away this property will still be there on the object which potentially could be a memory leak.

```html
<script>
let values = {}
</script>

{#each array as item}
  <input type="text" bind:value={values[item.id]}>
{/each}
```

A lost option is of course to simple use a new property on your original data

```html
{#each array as item}
  <input type="text" bind:value={item._newproperty}>
{/each}
```